# Making 2 admin modules for the same model in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I want to ask how to make 2 admin modules for the same model

I have a model called client. and I made an admin module for it with the name of client

now when I try to make another module with another name like client_2. I doesn't make it.

So, please help me guys, is this issue?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and found a solution,

1. go to the routing.yml and copy and paste the route of the first module for the model
2. Change the name of the route and the prefix path to client_2
3. Do "php symfony doctrine:generate-admin backend Client --module=client_2" and everything is fine i guess :P

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name of the module :

```
php symfony doctrine:generate-admin backend Client --module=client_2
```

Comment: I tried that .. but it doesn't work .. I read in another forum that there is something related to the routing file.

Comment: Can you explain what is the error when you try to access to the module client_2? And how are you accessing this module. Also provide the routes that refer to this module. Thanks

Comment: there is no error .. it just recreates the main client module in the cache .. and doesn't create the client_2 module at all .. when I try to access this module I get a 404 error page ..

Comment: Do you say that the module client_2 is not created ? And the route to this module is not created as well ?

Comment: If module files are not created you have a configuration problem somewhere. I cannot help you without more details on your config.I recommend to check your config or to try generate those 2 modules on a separate project to test.